# How to match and print consecutive backslash and dash (\-\-\-\-) from the input string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
x = "\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-"
```

The string could be any number of `\-` units.

I am using the following code to match `\-`

```
x = "\-\-\-"
v = re.findall("[\\-]*", x)
print(v)
```

The problem is, the pattern `[\\-]*` gives result:

```
 ['', '-', '', '-', '', '-', '']
```

If one uses three slashes, then the pattern gets a little clearer, but the result is still not right.

```
 v = re.findall("[\\\-]*", x)
```

It results in something like:

```
['\\-\\-\\-', '']
```

So? Any ideas on how to get it in the backslash dash backslash dash `\-\-` form?

Comment: why don't you use `r"\this"` - raw strings?

Comment: Why not `(\\-)`?

Comment: If you only want to match one instance of `\-`, why do you have `*`?

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall` tries to match captures groups (i.e. the portions of the regex that are enclosed in parentheses), and returns them in a list, rather than the matched string.
In this case the string `"\-\-\-"` has regular expression meta characters in it, hence it is escaped in the result you see in the list.
So you just need to retrieve the first element in the list to get it in string form.

```py
import re
x = '\-\-\-'
v = re.findall("[\\\-]*", x)[0]
print(v)
```

which gives the desired output:

```
\-\-\-
```